# PHP header on iframe POST form

Tags: php, html, iframe

I've a problem with a bootstrap webpage that im trying to fix it.

I have a page with a form. Inside the form there is a iframe.

The iframe contains a grid and some buttons. Click on a button show us a modal with other two buttons its which add rows to the iframe grid.

I do that with a form, but when i add new rows the page crash. The request status is pending and all the server gets stuck.

I think the problem could be something with the headers. They call "albaranes.nuevo.detalle2.php" which is the iframe itself.

Should i call exit after header? I thought that, but i have other mirror page for bills (this one is for delivery notes management) that works fine wwith no exit calls.

I used to use ajax for database calls and I'm very new with the forms and bootstrap. 
A new entry is added in the server log, but after reset it:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: https://*****/*****/albaranes.nuevo.detalle2.php
```

Some albaranes.nuevo.detalle2.php (iframe) code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['idUsuario'])){
  include 'includes/conexion_pruebas.php';
  include 'includes/funciones.php';




  //***********************************************************************************************************************************************
  // DIALOG ACCEPT BUTTON
  if ((isset($_POST['accion'])) && ($_POST['accion'] == 'nuevo')) {
    if($_POST['cantidad'] == 0){
      header ("Location: albaranes.nuevo.detalle2.php?id=".$idAlbaran.'&s='.$s.'&error=5'); 
    }else{
      //Con los ids de las lineas, las copiamos y las agregamos al nuevo albaran.
      foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
        //Working stuff
        //...
      }
      header ("Location: albaranes.nuevo.detalle2.php?id=".$idAlbaran."&s=".$s);
    }
  }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#barras">Barras</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevo">Nueva</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Dialog -->
  <div id="nuevo" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 80%">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="post" action="albaranes.nuevo.detalle2.php">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="nuevo" />
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar y Seguir" name="seguir" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Añadir y Cerrar" name="cerrar" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php  if(isset($_GET['s']) && ($_GET['s'] == '1')) { ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('#nuevo').modal('show');
        });
      </script>
  <?php  } ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
  header ("Location: login.php?error=1");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `header` function does not exit after it gets called, so if you want to make sure that nothing gets executed after the `header` call, you should put an `exit` there.

In the big if statement, you check for the value `cantidad`, which is never defined, so this if will never trigger. Though I don't think this is part of the problem.

In the else of the above mentioned if/else, you also loop through the `ids` value with a foreach loop. But again `ids` is never defined.

The problem is probably caused by some endless loop or timeout in the script of the `header` call.

Comment: All variables are defined, the posted code its only a fragment, but thanks for advises. I think exit calls will solution my problem, but i dont know why similar page without exit calls works and not this.